# Should I upgrade an old MacBook (2,1) to Mavericks?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have this old machine:

```
  Model Name:MacBook
  Model Identifier:MacBook2,1
  Processor Name:Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:2.16 GHz
  Number Of Processors:1
  Total Number Of Cores:2
  L2 Cache:4 MB
  Memory:3 GB
  Bus Speed:667 MHz
```

I've read that Mavericks is good for old machines ... but is this too old?
It's currently running 10.5.8.

Comment: Someone else said it was "not even possible" for you.  I have a "13-inch, Early 2009" with 10.8.  Every week or two, App Store reminds me about the free upgrade.  Is that happening for you?  (Or would it be Software Update in your case?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry ... according to http://www.apple.com/osx/specs/ it's not even possible!

Comment: It is posible. It requires some work and getting the GMA drivers to work with Mavericks, but it has been done for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it (I just did it to my ol' MacBook (mid 2007 - MacBook2,1) following http://zo0ok.com/techfindings/archives/1780).

Works a treat!

Only issues so far: iMessages throws an error (calling Apple Support tomorrow), and Brightness controls don't work (via F keys or System Preferences).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try installing it in an USB-flash drive, and see if it runs slow. 16GB size is enough.
I used to have a Core Duo machine (model code 1,2) and even the 10.4.10 updates turned the computer slower, it got me to a point to installing 10.4.4 and not updating just to keep it's speed (security risks considered).
What you could also do is to swap your HD to SSD, that usually increases overall system speed. Then put your old one into a USB-case and you have extra storage for almost no extra money.

Answer (score -1):

Lion works just fine on my 13inch white MacBook2,1 mid-2007. I'm thinking about a RAM upgrade, I got 2GB, will be upgrading to 6GB (yes, it's possible) and I'll replace my HD to an SSD.  After that I'll try upgrading to Mountain Lion and Mavericks... we'll see.